# Looking for a way to analyse transporter traffic on shopfloor (Density Map) in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I built up a shopfloor where material flow is realized by Transporters (AGV / AMR) with free space navigation. I am looking for a possibility to observe traffic at certain spots (e.g. work stations, storage areas) or even on the whole shopfloor so I can compare different scenarios of the material flow and supply strategy of the working station with a view on the traffic. I tried out the Density Map but since it observes the whole layout which is quite big the values get too low for the scale quite fast so it isn't performing the way I want it to. Is there a way so set up like a "area density map" so I can just observe a defined rectangle or another functionality which could help me here?
Happy about all ideas! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use normal `Rectangular Node` elements and trigger "on enter" code to count drive-throughs or similar, as below.

Just make sure to set the capacity to `infinity` so normal traffic flow is not interrupted :)

[image]

Comment: Note that the infinite capacity bit is needed just because access restrictions are needed to have the "On enter" action available. You could also restrict access by condition, with a condition of `false` (i.e., never restrict) which is a bit cleaner than a capacity of 'infinity'.

Comment: Agreed, didn't even check the other options :)